# Can a job be added to a resume even if I was only there for a short time?

Tags: professionalism, resume

I accepted a job which I resigned after the third day as I felt it was not meant for me, finding it intimidating and overwhelming. I am not sure if I should add those "three days" to my resume as part of my work experience. I am afraid I will be questioned and thought of as lying on my resume if I don't acknowledge that brief experience.

Comment: 3 days counts as experience?

Comment: Aren't you the same person who just asked this about a job you hadn't started? Is this the same job?

Comment: I would not bother - 3 days is hardly enough time to figure out how to work the coffee machine and find the toilet

Comment: Whew, by "short", I honestly expected a month or four. But three days, hmm.

Answer (score 13):

> Can a job be added to a resume even if I was only there for a short time?

**Can you? Sure. Should you? Nope.**

Your resume is a **marketing document** and you should only **list things that make you a better candidate**. You omit anything that doesn't accomplish that goal. That means that you don't bother listing jobs you've only been at for *days* rather than months. There's no experience to gain and leaving that quickly is a huge red flag for a candidate because it signals that you had a falling out, something was wrong with your background or skills, you're a bad judge of fit, impulsive or all of the above.

The one exception of course is jobs that were intended to be short-term like contracting gigs.

---

I was probably paraphrasing Alison Green again, [who has this to say on it](http://money.usnews.com/money/blogs/outside-voices-careers/2011/03/21/should-you-include-a-short-term-job-on-your-resume):

> If the job wasn’t intended to be short-term but ended up that way because you were fired or left after finding you hated the work or the people, you’re generally better off leaving it off your resume.
>
> Remember, your resume isn’t required to be a comprehensive accounting of how you spent each month of your professional life. It’s a marketing document intended to present you, your skills, and your experience in the strongest light.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and to answer that, I left because I am a new grad and did find myself quite overwhelmed within that work environment.

Answer (score 2):

No need to mention it. Don't worry about it at all. I doubt it would even come up in background checks. If it does, just say that while the company was great, the environment did not appeal to you, or something equally vague.

Just move on with your career.

Comment: In fact, I think mentioning it would actually be worse than leaving it off. You're more likely to draw attention to the fact that you only worked at a company for three days, marking you as a risk in their eyes.

Comment: The cost (to the company) of hiring someone who leaves (for whatever reason) after a few days would typically be quite large. And you likely don't want to work for a company that hires and fires impulsively.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost inappropriate to list the job.

Your resume is meant to provide (a) your experiences, and (b) what you've done with your time.  While it's true that having a hole in your timeline is cause for concern under (b), plenty of people will have a gap of a week or so between jobs. Even when someone leaves one job for another, it's not uncommon to take a little break.

After enough decades, you'll leave off jobs simply because they're no longer relevant (that COBOL experience on a PDP probably won't help land the next big position). It's clear that your three days is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason to mention it, but be prepared to answer questions.

Have your START stories ready.

- S = Situation,
- T usually is Task but in this case it is rather Treat,
- A = Action,
- R = Result and
- T = Transfer = lessons learned

For instance

- S : "Indeed, I applied for this job and was hired."
- T : "In my first days there I realized I would never feel at ease in this company because ..." (The art here is to convince without being too negative. Negative stories don't sell.)
- A : "So I resigned"
- R : "And got hired at ..."
- T : "Since then I inform myself better about the company culture before applying. Your employee John Doe really convinced me this is a grate place to work."